# Getting current time via Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, datetime, browser, cross-browser

A two-part question:

1. What is the best way to get the current time from JavaScript?
2. What resolution can I assume across all major platforms (including browser-capable PDAs, iPhone, etc.) -- seconds, milliseconds, 1/10th of a second?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `var date = new Date();`. `new Date().getTime()` will return you the number of milliseconds since January 1 1970.
2. Milliseconds. It's specified as such in the ECMAScript spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this page for function work for time.

http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm

There may no compatible issue. Since it is standardized